# Minimum value of $S = |x_2-x_1| + |x_3 - x_2| + |x_4-x_3| + \cdots + |x_{100}-x_{99}| + |x_{100} - x_1| $

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math, combinations

> Consider the set of integers $\{1,2,3,4,\cdots,100\}$. Let $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4, \cdots, x_{100}\}$ be some arbitrary arrangement of the previous set, Where each $x_i$ is different. Find the minimum value of the sum:
>   $$S = |x_2-x_1| + |x_3 - x_2| + |x_4-x_3| + \cdots + |x_{100}-x_{99}| + |x_{100} - x_1|  $$

I think the sum will be minimum if the set is sorted. As we don't have any negative number in the sum. But I am worried about $|x_{100} - x_{99}|$. If I assume that the set is sorted then the sum will be $99 + 99 = 198$. I think this is wrong. Or I cant show any proof to this solution. If this is the right answer then how do I prove this?
**Source**: BdMO 2016 Secondary National

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S$ does not change with a *cyclic* permutation of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4, \cdots, x_{100})$, therefore we can assume that $x_1 = 1$.
Then $x_m = 100$ for some $m \ge 2$ and the triangle equality gives
$$
 S = \left(|x_2-x_1| + |x_3-x_2|+\ldots + |x_m-x_{m-1}| \right) 
 + \left(|x_{m+1}-x_m| + \ldots |x_{100} -x_{99}| + |x_1 - x_{100}| \right) \\
\ge |x_1 - x_m| + |x_m - x_1| \\
= 2 (100-1) = 198
$$
so you have indeed found the minimal value.

Comment: Why we assume that $x_1 = 1 \& x_m  = 100$?

Comment: @RezwanArefin: The sum does not change  with a *cylic* permutation of the numbers. So you may assume that $x_1=1$. Then $x_m=100$ must hold for *some* $m > 1$.

Comment: $x_1 = 1$ why? still didn't get this

Comment: @RezwanArefin: $S$ does not change if you replace $(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_{100})$ by $(x_2, x_3,\cdots, x_{100}, x_1)$ (a "cyclic permutation" or "rotation"). So you can rotate the values until  the first one is equal to $1$.

Comment: Now got it .. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Place the $\{1,2,\cdots 100\}$ in that order evenly spaced on a straight line. Then each term in $S$ may be represented by a line segment connecting two of the integers.  Moreover, each integer appears in precisely two such line segments, and there will be no ccyles of length less than $100$ among those segments.

Focus on the term in $S$ containing the number $1$; since there are two such terms, for concreteness, choose the term containing the lower of the other numbers. Then following each line segment we have a path $P$ of length $100$, starting and ending at $1$.  Let's examine some properties of $P$:

- $P$ starts from $1$, reaches (at some step) $100$, and returns to $1$.  Thus the length of $P$ must be at least $99+99=198$.
- The particular path $P$ that moves from $1$ to $2$ to $3\ldots$ and finally returns from $100$ to $1$ is of length $198$

Thus the minimal path  is of length $198$ and so is the minimal value of $S$.